# Embedding Simple Facebook Connect login button to sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Simple Facebook Connect plugin on our site, because we want our users to be able to authenticate via Facebook. That functionality works great on wp-login.php as the "FB Login" button appears properly over there, but what I need is to get that "FB Login" button on the sidebar or header.

I searched a lot for the same but still have got no solution to this one.

Can anyone offer any good suggestions here?

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this solution as well so that I can add it to the header of a theme of a client's site and after searching online and on the WordPress plugins forum I gave up and decided to look at their code to figure it out.  I was able to copy this following code into the header and it worked.

```
<?php echo '<p><fb:login-button v="2" scope="email,user_website" onlogin="window.location.reload();" /></p><br />';?>
```

Of course you can remove the p and br tags to fit into your theme or sidebar as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I do not have a good answers.  For now, I have redirected the user to the login page using:

```
wp_login_url( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] )
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem of getting login in the sidebar?

Comment: This does't solve the problem but serve another way to accomplish the login task. Now I use [**Nextend Facebook Connect**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextend-facebook-connect/) for social login